# Installing Prototype Widgets in Orange running on Mac

Tags: orange

I am having trouble downloading some add-ons for the Orange data mining software that are not available through the normal add-ons menu. To do this, I am attempting to install a particular set of add-ons from the GitHub page [here](http://git@github.com:biolab/orange3-prototypes.git).

I am very novice when it comes to using Terminal and terminal commands. Could anyone help provide some insight on how to install this package?

Some people have suggested that they should appear in the list of the prototypes, but they do not. Does anyone have Orange running on Mac so that they can try this to see if it works?

Specifics for the exact code that I need to implement in the terminal to get this to work would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to install Orange's addons is through the application itself. Open Orange, in the menu click `Options -> Addons`. In the popup window mark `Orange3-Prototypes` and click OK. Note, that by doing so you will get the latest version that is published on PyPI.

If you would want to install the bleeding edge version directly from GitHub — assuming that you installed Orange by downloading a bundle from its website and not for example by using Anaconda — do the following. Open a terminal and paste this command:

Doing so you will trigger the `pip` that came with the bundle and instruct it to install the addon directly from Github.

Further, to install `opencv`, which is required by some widgets (e.g. webcamecapture) run

Note, however, that this is an unofficial version of OpenCV but it seems easier to install.

Comment: This particular cutting edge package is not available through the Addons->Install tab. Also, did you try this yourself? I just did this and they still are not appearing in Orange when I launch it.

Comment: Ethan, it think that currently, the version on github is the same as on PyPi. Check the [code on github](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-prototypes/commits/master). The latest commit I see is the version bump to version 0.4.9, which is exactly what I see on Pypi. Of course I tried it myself and it worked. Do you see `Orange3-Prototypes` in the list if you run `/Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS/pip list`?

Comment: Aaaahh, I see. I misunderstood that you do not see the whole Prototypes section, and not that just some widgets are missing. The reason you do not see the Webcam capture widget is in the missing `opencv` dependency. You can try to install it by `/Applications/Orange3.app/Contents/MacOS/pip install opencv-python`. Note however that this is unofficial version of opencv but it seems easier to install.

Comment: You just made my day! :) Thank you so much! After a week of trying to figure out how to do this I finally got it to work! The widgets are now showing up like they should when I launch Orange. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great to hear this! I also updated the above answer with this additional info for others.

Comment: I think `jpeg`, `jpg` and `png` should all work.